# Не находит элемент в таблице

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Есть таблица с именем `place-car`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данной таблице отвечает Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "place-car" )
public class PlaceCarTable{

    @Id
    @Column( name = "id" )
    private int id;

    @Column( name = "idcar" )
    private int carId;

    @Column( name = "idplace" )
    private int placeId;

    @Column( name = "timeBegin" )
    private int timeBegin;

    @Column( name = "timeEnd" )
    private int timeEnd;


    public PlaceCarTable(  ){

    }
```

Необходимо вынуть из этой таблицы выделенную строку, это происходит в методе:

```
public Place isPark( String numbCar ){
    CarTable carTable = selectWithCriteriaSingle( CarTable.class, "numbCar", numbCar  );
    PlaceCarTable placeCarTable = selectWithCriteriaSingle( PlaceCarTable.class, "carId", carTable.getTsId(), "timeEnd", -1 );

    if( placeCarTable != null ){
        PlaceDAO placeDAO = new PlaceDAO();
        return placeDAO.selectPlace( placeCarTable.getPlaceId() );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Строка должна вернуться в `placeCarTable`, вот описание функции `selectWithCriteriaSingle`:

```
public <T, V1, V2> T selectWithCriteriaSingle( Class Table, String field1, V1 value1, String field2, V2 value2 ) throws HibernateException{
    try {
        connect();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery( Table );
        Root<T> root = query.from( Table );
        query.select( root ).where( builder.equal( root.get( field1), value1 ), builder.equal( root.get( field2), value2 ));
        Query<T> q = session.createQuery( query );
        return ( T ) q.getSingleResult();
    }catch( Exception ex ){
        System.out.println( ex );
        return null;
    }finally {
        disconnect();
    }
}
```

Данная функция запрашивает у базы данных строку, в которой `field1 = value1` и `field2 = value2` ( `value1 = 1` и `value2 = -1`, это я проверял дебагером ), но функция выкидывает исключение:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Привет.
Меня смущает строка

```
query.select( root ).where( builder.equal( root.get( field1), value1 ), builder.equal( root.get( field2), value2 ));
```

Мне кажется не хватает builder.and(...)

```
query.select( root ).where(builder.and(builder.equal( root.get( field1), value1 ), builder.equal( root.get( field2), value2 )));
```

Comment: Добавил, не помогло